# Tomcat - Persistent Object

Tags: database, memory, tomcat

I am running a servlet that recommends items based on a data model. The data model has to be loaded into an object from a database each time user makes a request to the sever and since the data is the same for all the users I would like this object to be loaded once only. I am very new to Tomcat and don't know where to look so any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this wasn't the smartest question. Any object within the RemoteServiceServlet is shared between the queries.